# Appium. Cannot find module 'appium-base-driver'

Tags: android, appium, npm-install, python-appium

My appium GUI was working perfectly fine until today. When I tried to start appium I am getting this error. I don't know how to get around it. So any suggestions / solutions highly appreciated.

```
    Launching Appium with command: '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node' appium/build/lib/main.js --pre-launch --debug-log-spacing --automation-name "Appium" --platform-name "Android" --platform-version "6.0" --app "/Users/iamtheuser/fitbit/automation/artifacts/myapp.apk" --language "en" --locale "US"

Error: Cannot find module 'appium-base-driver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (lib/main.js:7:58)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:146:18)
    at node.js:404:3
```

Comment: Maybe reinstall Appium.app would fix your error

Comment: What version are you using ?

Answer (score 3):

Install Appium Doctor and investigate whats wrong in it.

1. Install Appium Doctor by below command:

   ```
   npm install appium-doctor -g
   ```
2. Use Appium Doctor by below command:

   ```
   appium-doctor -h
   ```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you might :

1. updated appium version
2. might updated all other installed/removed gems/dependancies like nodeJS

Do you remember what activity have you done?

Answer (score 1):

You can install the base driver by below command:

```
npm i appium-base-driver
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install `appium-base-driver` by running following command from your command prompt

```
npm i appium-base-driver
```

If still the error is there then try installing it globally using below command

```
npm install -g appium-base-driver
```

If its not adding packages try with

```
npm install -g gulp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try
Intall gulp with npm install -g gulp

Answer (score 0):

The issue has happened because you might have updated java-client but not the appium server.

Say if your java-client version is 6.0.0-BETA4, you need to use Appium v1.7.2

Please update how you resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

@Mysterio Man, hi . Could You please share what versions: java-client/appium GUI do You use ?
I'd recommend to try the following alternatives:

- Install gulp using `npm -g gulp`
- check for versions of [appium GUI](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases)
- check for [java-client](https://github.com/appium/java-client) versions   ;  [Maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client)

In my proj I'm using [dependency](https://docs.experitest.com/display/public/TA/Grid+-+Appium+driver)

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Works fine for me.
And also installing appium i accurately followed this [step-by-step setup instruction](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/download-and-install-appium-1-6/)   . Didnt face any issues.
In worst case- might be helpful to reinstall everything from scratch.
Let me know if You have resolved the issue.
Regards,
Eugene

Answer (score 0):

Hey I also had the same issue,

1. check the node version you have
2. check if you have installed command line version of appium [there might be a chance of conflicts if both cli and gui are installed]
3. final option would be better uninstall node and appium & re-install both.

Cheers,
Have a great day

Answer (score 0):

Please update your Appium version and try again

Comment: please provide more detail in your answer like how it should be updated or at least why it's necessary to update. Your current answer can be a simple comment.

Comment: Most of the Appium server client related issues are related to version variations and the correlations.  I have been working with Appium for 4 years and most of the issues are resolved when updated to the latest version of Appium. That is my answer. looks like simple but values lot.please refer Appium forums for latest versions and the procedure how to update. Knowing how to install and update or degrade versions are basic knowledge to be had.

Answer (score 0):

let's try the global installation again. please follow these steps:

move out of your project directory entirely to somewhere else on your system cd ~
uninstall appium npm uninstall -g appium
unset APPIUM_HOME export APPIUM_HOME=""
rm -rf ~/.appium
install appium npm install -g appium@next
confirm no drivers/plugins installed appium driver list (should show none installed)
install driver appium driver install uiautomator2
run appium appium
what happens when you do these steps?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).